# CheckBox in ListView deactivated when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` where each `ListItem` has a `CheckBox` in it's layout. When a `CheckBox` is activated and scrolls out of the visible area, it's getting deactivated. I understand `ListView` reuses the `Views` and that i have to save the state of the `CheckBoxes` in my `getView()` method, but i have two problems there.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call setSelected on a String. You need to call it on the checkbox. the variable "list" is an ArrayList of Strings.

In both cases, you are trying to call Checkbox methods on String types. You need to call them on your checkboxes.

**EDIT

What you need to do in getView is the following:

1. if the convertView is not null, save the state of it to your "viewholder" class by calling the appropriate methods on the children of convertView. You are trying to do this if the convertView IS null, which is wrong.
2. If the convertView is null, then it isn't a recycled view, and there is nothing to save.

basically, your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
    } else {
        //you should change viewHolder to simply store a boolean, rather than the entire checkbox. It should just store whether or not the checkbox was checked.
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listcontent);
        viewHolder.isChecked = ((CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb)).isChecked();
        //do whatever else here
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Ok i thought this is getting the position in the list and then checking if it's selected. I now made the changes that you suggested, but calling to checkBox throws the error "checkBox cannot be resolved". "checkBox.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());". It also doesn't work with prefix viewHolder.

Comment: checkbox is not an accessible variable, it is a member in your ViewHolder class.

Comment: Something's wrong with your code. When I'm scrolling, it randomly actives/deactivates Checkboxes that leave the visible area.

Comment: you have to set them to be rechecked based on saving the states to your ViewHolder objects. Keep a stored list of the states of your checkboxes for instance... Keep a list of "state" objects which is what I assume your ViewHolder is for. When you call getView, get the state from your arraylist of viewholders(and pick index position), and reset the checkbox in the view to what it should be. My code is not complete, it's meant as a guideline for what you intend to do.